# request call using http get with query parameters is not working

Tags: python, web-scraping

what i want to do is simple:

- Importing the requests library, which allows making HTTP requests.
- Defining the URL for the API endpoint to "https://busquedas.elperuano.pe/api/v1/elvis".
- Setting up the query parameters for the request, including `from_date`, `to_date`, `page`, and `scope`. The dates are in the format "dd-mm-yyyy", and the "page" parameter is set to 0.
- Initializing empty payload since it is a GET request and doesn't require a request body.
- Defining the headers to be used in the request. These headers specify details about the request, such as the "Accept" content type and the "User-Agent" identifying the client (browser).
- Making the HTTP GET request using the requests.request() method and storing the response in the response variable.
- Finally, printing the text content of the response using response.text.

but i get an error doing it

[image: here is the error]

also the code is here:

```
import requests

url = "https://busquedas.elperuano.pe/api/v1/elvis"

querystring = {"from_date":"01-01-1996","page":"0","scope":"false","to_date":"21-07-2023"}

payload = ""
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Language": "es-ES,es;q=0.7",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "https://busquedas.elperuano.pe/",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-GPC": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "sec-ch-ua": "^\^Not/A",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "^\^Windows^^"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

i dont really have any idea on how to solve it but i really want someone to help me pls

Comment: Why do you use this strange character  ^ , "^\^Windows^^" ? Should this not be like, Sec-CH-UA-Platform: "windowsOS"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put `verify=False` argument to `requests.get` (but more correct approach would be to install correct certificates):

```py
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

# Suppress only the single warning from urllib3 needed.
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "https://busquedas.elperuano.pe/api/v1/elvis"
querystring = {"from_date":"01-01-1996","page":"0","scope":"false","to_date":"21-07-2023"}

response = requests.get(url, params=querystring, verify=False)
print(response.json())
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "totalHits": 1838426,
    "hits": [
        {
            "originalUrl": "http://172.20.0.102:8080/file/AFLJl8jEqkuBnKanE_Ky-F/*/2198191-1.pdf?_=2",
            "highlightedText": "Firmado por: Editora\nPeru\nFecha: 21/07/2023 01:26\n\nNORMAS LEGALES\n\nEl Peruano / Viernes 21 de julio de 2023\n\nN\u00b0\n\nNOMBRES\n\n1.\n\nDONATO\n\nAPELLIDO PATERNO APELLIDO MATERNO\n\n29\n\nDNI\n\nDISTRITO\nLUCMA\n\nPROVINCIA\nMARISCAL\nLUZURIAGA\n\nREGION\nANCASH\n\nBONIFACI...",
            "url_link": "/normaslegales/designan-directora-ii-de-la-oficina-de-planeamiento-presupu-resolucion-d000085-2023-conadis-pre-2198191-1/",
            "previewUrl": "http://172.20.0.102:8080/preview/AFLJl8jEqkuBnKanE_Ky-F/previews/maxWidth_1600_maxHeight_1600_page_0.jpg/*/2198191-1_preview.jpg?_=1",
            "permissions": "VPWUMERXCD",
            "thumbnailUrl": "http://172.20.0.102:8080/thumbnail/AFLJl8jEqkuBnKanE_Ky-F/*/2198191-1_thumb.jpg?_=1",
            "id": "AFLJl8jEqkuBnKanE_Ky-F",
            "metadata": {
                "subjectCode": "D000085-2023-CONADIS-PRE",
                "instanceId": "uuid:a34ae206-29ea-11ee-0000-7486721dafe4",
                "height": 780,
                "edition": "558",
                "publicationDate": {
                    "formatted": "2023-07-21 00:00:00 -0500",
                    "value": 1689915600000
                },
                "category": "NL",
                "assetType": "pdf",
                "assetPath": "/Shared Zone/NNLL y BBOO/2023/07/21/2198191-1.pdf",
                "subjectOrganizationCode": "2198191-1",
                "section": "2080",
                "filename": "2198191-1.pdf",
                "previewETag": 1,
                "width": 489,
                "assetDomain": "pdf",
                "description": "Designan Directora II de la Oficina de Planeamiento, Presupuesto y Modernizaci\u00f3n del CONADIS",
                "editionName": "PODER EJECUTIVO",
                "volume": "--",
                "contentETag": 2,
                "slug": "designan-directora-ii-de-la-oficina-de-planeamiento-presupu-resolucion-d000085-2023-conadis-pre-2198191-1",
                "documentId": "uuid:a34ae206-29ea-11ee-0000-7486721dafe4",
                "previewState": "yes",
                "numberOfPages": 2,
                "name": "2198191-1.pdf",
                "sectionName": "SEPARATAS DE NORMAS LEGALES",
                "industry": "RESOLUCION",
                "thumbnailState": "yes",
                "numberOfPreviewPages": 2
            }
        },

...
```

---

NOTE: I've removed the unnecessary `headers=` and `payload=` arguments.